# how to replace some part of text from the text file in php

Tags: php, fopen, fclose

I'm trying to delete/edit some portion of text from text file, like if I have 10 lines in my text file then I want to edit 5th line or delete 3rd line without affecting any other line.

Currently what I'm doing
1. open text file and read data in php variable
2. done editing on that variable
3. delete the content of text file.
4. write new content on it

but is there any way to doing that thing without deleting whole content or by just edit those content?

my current code is like this

```
$file = fopen("users.txt", "a+");
$data = fread($file, filesize("users.txt"));
fclose($file);
$newdata = str_replace($old, $new, $data);
file_put_contents("users.txt", "");
$file = fopen("users.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, $newdata);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten that to:

```
$data = file_get_contents("users.txt");
$newdata = str_replace($old, $new, $data);
file_put_contents("users.txt", $newdata);
```

Comment: that I already did in my code using fopen and fread, fwrite and fclose.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '';
$lines = file("users.txt");
foreach($lines as $line_no=>$line_txt)
{
$line_no += 1; // Start with zero 
//check the line number and concatenate the string 
if($line_no == 5)
{
// Append the $str with your replaceable text
}
else{
$str .= $line_txt."\n";
}
}
// Then overwrite the $str content to same file
// i.e file_put_contents("users.txt", $str);
```

I have added solution as per my understanding, Hope it will help!!!

Comment: again after storing new data in $str, again I have to upload it again that I already did in my code

Comment: the problem is to replace a pre-determined line number text to a specific text (right?). And i think this is a one of the simple solution. this is what i got. 
If you have specific text that you wanted to replace with one or more place than you can go with solution by @aderuwe. 

but if you wanted to replace text once then this could help probably 
`preg_replace(TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED, TEXT_WANTED, FROM_STRING, 1)`

Comment: what you want.....

    1) line number text to be replaced
<br />
    2) pre-determined text to be Replace

          a) first occurrence 

          b) all occurrence

Comment: preg_replace is for regular expression and same thing I did with str_replace, but for replacing text in text file first you have to fetch all the data from it, then replace the new text with old and delete current content from file and rewrite the new content, it can be done with str_replace or preg_replace

Comment: yes, but your problem is to replace with LINE NUMBER text? and `str_replace or preg_replace` is used to replace with text(string) by text and for text.
make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can work on each line:

```
$lines = file("users.txt");
foreach($lines as &$line){
  //do your stufff 
  // $line is one line
  //
}
$content = implode("", $lines);
//now you can save $content like before
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but using this code, I have to overwrite the whole data again,

Answer (score 0):

If you've only got 10 lines in your text file, then unless they are very long lines you're changing the amount of physical I/O required to change the contents (disks will only read/write data one *physical* sector at a time - and the days of 512byte sectors are long gone).

Yes, you can modify a large file by only writing the sectors which have changed - but that requires that you replace the data with something the same size to prevent framing errors (in PHP using fopen with mode c+, fgets/fseek/fwrite/ftell, fclose).

Really the corect answer is to stop storing multivalued data in a text file and use a DBMS (which also solves the concurrency issues).

Comment: database is always the best solution, but I just want to know that as I got this as my college assignments and when data become large it takes more time to load, so I just try to find a solution, thanks for exaplanation.